# How to iterate a Summation function over two variable?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a summation function `q[i]*f[j]` which runs over `i` and `j` of same length with different limits. Following I provided an example, where `q` is in list form:

```
q={2,7,11};
```

and `f[j]` runs over `-1, 0 and 1`.
The output of this summation function should be:

```
ouptput= 2*f[-1]+7*f[0]+11*f[1];
```

So far, I have been able to iterate `f[j]` over `j` and using `Sum` to add, as following:

```
In: Sum[f[j], {j, -1, 1}]
Out: f[-1] + f[0] + f[1]
```

But how to iterate `q[i]` values provided in listform above  and multiply to `f[j]`  finnaly get following:

```
ouptput= q[[1]]*f[-1]+q[[2]]*f[0]+q[[3]]*f[1];
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a [vector product](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html):

```
q = {2, 7, 11};
jval = Range[-1, 1];

q . (f /@ jval)
(*    2 f[-1] + 7 f[0] + 11 f[1]    *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked.